# Fragment loading animation don't start until startactivity intent completed in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

There are two activities which are main and reding. When I click the open book in main activity, a loading fragment should be appear on screen until reading activity loaded completely.

In activity main, activity reading open click event:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        // fragment fade in enough
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, 0, 0, 0)
        // main_root in activity main.
        .add(R.id.main_root, new BookLoadingFragment(), "BookLoaderFragment")
        .addToBackStack("BookLoaderFragmentStackTag")
        .commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReadBookActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

So by the above code, loading fragment don't appear until reading activity opened completely (It appear without setCustomAnimations()). I've tried creating new thread or async task for fragment but there was an error creating fragmet not allowed outside of ui thread. Also I've to create fragment in main activity because reading activity has many other fragments attached it with onActivityCreated().

Comment: Have you tried to start the new activity with transparent background and when it's fully loaded to set the color back of what you want? It is possible that new activity just overlaps the fragment that you want to show because it belongs to the previous activity.

Comment: Second activity suddenly opening after 1-2 second overlaping isn't possible, I've to add loading fragment because of second avtivity delay

Comment: have you tried to force finish the first activity by calling finish(); before after calling  context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Closing first activity and opening application with fragment with finish(), looks very bad :)

Comment: You can set callback to backstack changes in fragment manager. Try starting readbookactivity inside callback method.

Comment: Doesn't matter, also fragment content freezing when intent started

Comment: Actually, after rereading question, i don't get the purpose of loadingFragment. It's not that it servers as loader until some data fetched. You r showing fragment and immediately starting new activity, thus that fragment gets immediately hidden coz its hosted by previous activity.
Try  Handler().postDelayed({
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReadBookActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
},1500) 

so activity gets started after 1.5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your BookLoadingFragment freezing because main ui thread is no longer at its activity, you cannot work on it anymore. You should add loading fragment in what activity you load and show loading fragment until loaded second activity with AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_book);
    
    AddLoadingFragment();
    new AsyncLoading().execute();
}

class AsyncLoading extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {
    
    public AsyncAppOpen() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // Preapare background process only! Get data from Database or build Rcyvlerview adapter.
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        // doInBackground finished and it's time to preapare ui thread process. Build RecyclerView or some ui tools.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public final class BookLoadingFragment extends Fragment {

   ...

   public void onViewCreated(@NotNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
      Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(), ReadBookActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Start `ReadBookActivity` after `BookLoadingFragment` was created

Comment: You're right it's working, but the purpose of the loading is to save time, BookLoadingFragment opening 300ms loss because of anim.

Comment: Animating fragment uses a main thread, also Starting activity uses a main thread. You said "It appear without setCustomAnimations()", Of course. It works correctly.

Because main thread can’t do many things at once.

Unfortunately It is recommended to run sequentially. Sorry that can't provide any solutions